# Find best producrion order

Tags: sorting

I run embroidery machines that make custom bags for whole sale. We have two and each can hold up to 12 colors of thread. One of the most time intensive tasks is changing threads. Normal I pick the next patten that has all or some of the same colors as the last.

If I had a sheet with every design and all the needed thread colors by number they require how would I even begin to write a program to order the list to show the best order to make the bags to minimize thread changes.

I would think it would need to see how many patterns had overlapping colors and what colors are used more and what don't.

I don't even know if this cns be done or even how I would code it.

Some advice would be welcome.

EDIT:
So a little more info to help make things more clear. When we get an order it will be a list of designs and what kind of bags those will go on. Each design had between 1 and 7 colors in it. Some colors are shared between designs. I can easily have a reffrence sheet listing the colors needed for each patten. What I am trying to figure out is how do I evaluate all the designs in an order to find the best order to produce them with the most overlap of colors to minimize change over.

Comment: How many different colours do you have?

Comment: There are probably other factors to this optimization problem, including the maximum number of partially-complete bags you can have, the time cost of switching bags, _etc_. It doesn't seem particularly trivial. It's also hard to answer in generic terms with no idea of your actual programming knowledge. The first approach I might consider is to develop a dependency graph for your patterns that represents not only the colors needed but also any ordering due to overlap. It's likely some patterns must break into multiple steps. After that, this becomes a graph optimization problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically Multiple Travelling Salesman problem, but instead of two salesmen travel time to cities, you have thread-changing time of two machines. Instead of having to visit each city, each pattern needs to be produced. The cost ("distance") function is the time needed for the switch between two patterns.

For a more realistic example, I think you should actually have the cost be the total time for a pattern, starting from switching threads, but also including the embroidery time for the pattern batch, otherwise you can end up with the thread changing times being balanced, but one machine could get all the jobs for 3 bags each, and the other all the jobs with 1000 bags each, if the embroidery time is not calculated into the cost function.

For example, I believe you can adapt [this solution](https://colab.research.google.com/github/cvxpy/cvxpy/blob/master/examples/notebooks/WWW/mTSP_en.ipynb). The only difference is that you would be starting with a distance matrix (by calculating the cost function for each pair of patterns), you would not need to calculate it from coordinates (because you don't have coordinates).

Comment: So that is a good starting point but maybe I did not describe what I am trying to do well enough. Most patterns have between one and 6 colors. Some patterns share colors with other patterns, the machine has a max of 12 colors it can have at anyone one time. I would like to have a function that looks at all the colors needed for a whole set of patterns and give an initial setup and order to produce that would have the lease amount of change over.